# What is the biblical basis for typology between Moses and Jesus?

Tags: biblical-basis, life-of-jesus, christology, moses, typology

Does there exist a typology between Moses and Jesus Christ? My friend is a Roman Catholic and said that Jesus is the new Moses, is this true and if so what biblical evidence exists for this?

Comment: There is also contrast e.g. John 1:17 which suggests something more than just a new Moses.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is made in Acts 3:22-23, where Peter makes the connection between Jesus and the promise in Deut 18:15 that God would send another prophet like Moses.

---

Other than this direct connection, there is a typology here:

- Moses is the prophet that delivered Israel physically (from slavery), and Jesus does the same spiritually
- Moses gave the covenant, Jesus gave a new covenant (Heb 8)
- Moses instituted the ordinances/sacrifices etc. which were symbolic for Christ and his sacrifice (Heb 9)